# Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery in ReacJS

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';
```

When `import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';` 
then Error Message`

Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.

Comment: Are you by chance using webpack or some other bundler?

Comment: simply npm install bootstrap --save   and them import library in project bootstrap.css is supported but bootstrap.js is not supported

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap requires jquery to be available on the global object. Try the below -

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const $ = require('jquery');
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = $;
require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min');
```

This is verified for bootstrap@3.3.7 and jquery@2.2.4.

Ref - [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5542#issuecomment-432298925)

Answer (score 0):

when I want to use actuall bootstrap I Add the CDN in the index.html as the following

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

use npm i bootstrap
to download the required files.
an then use the bootstrap in your project as html
but if you want you can use react-strap or react-bootstrap for better javascript  manipulation